# Webscraping in R https & webform

Tags: r, web-scraping

I'm trying to webscrape data from this site: `https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/k-12-school-code-search` per US state. I'm fairly new to webscraping but I know one can scrape data from a `https` page.

This is what I tried:

```
library(httr)

url <- "https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/k-12-school-code-search"

AL <- list(
    submit = "submit",
    state  = Alabama
)
```

Neither "Alabama" nor "AL" worked.

I wanted to see if I could get a data frame for each state and unfortunately with this site there isn't a specific page for each state.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, I was able to get the form filled as follows :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate("https://collegereadiness.collegeboard.org/k-12-school-code-search")
Sys.sleep(2)

web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-state")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "AZ"
Sys.sleep(2)

doc <- IEApp$Document()
clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)
obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementById("edit-submit")
obj$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
Sys.sleep(2)

text <- doc$documentElement()$innerText()

# Now, we have to clean the text, but the values are there ...
```

Also, here are examples of how to access the other elements of the form :

```
web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-school-name")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "..."

web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-country")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "..."

web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-city")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "..."

web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-zip")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "..."

web_Obj <- IEApp$Document()$getElementByID("edit-proximity")
web_Obj$Click()
web_Obj$Focus()
web_Obj[["Value"]] <- "..."
```