# Translating text in R

Tags: r, translation, google-translate

When looking for a solution to translate text within `R`, I got a lot of pretty old answers, proposing to use the package `translateR`. The best answer I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36601465/8071608).

The answer is 6 years old and in the meantime `translateR` is no longer part of the CRAN repository (anyone know why?). I was wondering if there are better options by now, that use a package that is in the CRAN repository.

My example data is as follows;

```
translate <- data.frame(sentences = c("This needs to be translated to Dutch",
               "This also needs to be translated to Dutch",
               "Just as this one has to"))
```

What is currently the best option to translate text within R?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `deeplr` package which uses [deepl](https://www.deepl.com/translator)'s [API](https://www.deepl.com/pro-api?cta=header-pro-api). Deepl is supposedly much more accurate than Google translate.

```r
library(deeplr)
translate2(text = translate$sentences, 
           source_lang = "EN",
           target_lang = "NL",
           auth_key = "your_key")

#[1] "Dit moet vertaald worden naar het Nederlands"    
#[2] "Dit moet ook vertaald worden naar het Nederlands"
#[3] "Net als deze moet"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that can be used which basically calls a python library from R :

```
library(reticulate)
conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "traduction") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "traduction", packages = c("transformers"))
}

reticulate::use_condaenv("traduction")
py_run_string("from transformers import pipeline")
py_run_string("translator = pipeline('translation_en_to_fr')")
py_run_string("print(translator('It is easy to translate languages with transformers', max_length=40))")

[{'translation_text': "Il est facile de traduire des langues à l'aide de transformateurs"}]
```

This approach does not need an API and runs locally. You can also consider the following approach which also runs locally :

```
library(reticulate)
conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "traduction") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "traduction", packages = c("transformers"))
}

reticulate::use_condaenv("traduction")

transformers <- import("transformers")
translator <- transformers$pipeline('translation_en_to_fr')
translator('It is easy to translate languages with transformers', max_length=40)

[[1]]
[[1]]$translation_text
[1] "Il est facile de traduire des langues à l'aide de transformateurs"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach based on google translate :

```
library(stringr)
library(pagedown)
library(pdftools)
text_To_Translate <- "La tutela de Vieux-la-Romaine est une "
text_To_Translate <- str_replace_all(string = text_To_Translate, pattern = "[:space:]", replacement = "%20")
url <- paste0('https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&text=', text_To_Translate, '&op=translate')
temp_PDF <- tempfile(fileext = ".pdf")
tryCatch(pagedown::chrome_print(input = url, output = temp_PDF, wait = 2), error = function(e) NA)
translated_Text <- pdf_text(temp_PDF)
translated_Text <- strsplit(translated_Text, split = "\r\n|\n")[[1]]
translated_Text <- translated_Text[c(12, 13)]
translated_Text[1] <- str_remove(string = translated_Text[1], pattern = "         clear")
str_split(translated_Text, "[:space:]{20,100}")

[[1]]
[1] "La tutela de Vieux-la-"    "The guardian of Vieux-la-"

[[2]]
[1] "Romaine est une" "Romaine is a"
```

Comment: I get stopped by at pagedown line, as Google requests cookie acceptance, so what I get is the pdf of the cookie page. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, yes, but I need more details on your error. If you can provide more information on your error, I could provide ideas.

Comment: As I wrote in my original comment, I get a standard "accept cookies" page into my pdf rather than the translation result. Not sure if I can do something in Chrome settings to prevent this behavior on default guest profile... Thank you for looking into this

Comment: I added another answer below based on internet explorer. On my end, it works well with internet explorer. We could use a similar approach with RSelenium with Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: 1. Are referring to your python solution? 2. In this solution (I cannot install this python right now here): How do you get chrome_print to work through IE? I thought it opens headless Chrome and a clean Chrome asks for cookie acceptance. I get the same pdf as when I open Chrome with Guest profile, so the command works "correctly", but it produces no translation...

Comment: Edit: I did reset to Microsoft Edge through `browser` input, but I get the same: a cookie page, also through the Edge (just like though headless Chrome)

Comment: I was referring to the solution with RDCOMClient below. You can simply extract the translated text with internet.explorer from R.

Comment: Thanks. I have commented on the other solution. As to this one, I have tried to pass User info and cookies to Chrome, but `extra_args` does not seem to have its intended effect or I am not specifying all I should (or how I should) for it to work (to pass cookies etc from the profile)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach that can be used to translate from english to dutch :

```
library(reticulate)

conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "traduction") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "traduction", packages = c("transformers", "SentencePiece"), python_version = "3.9.16")
  reticulate::conda_install(envname = "traduction", packages = "torch", pip = TRUE)
}  

reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "traduction")
transformers <- import(module = "transformers")

tokenizer <- transformers$AutoTokenizer$from_pretrained("yhavinga/t5-small-24L-ccmatrix-multi")
model <- transformers$AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM$from_pretrained("yhavinga/t5-small-24L-ccmatrix-multi")

translator <- transformers$pipeline("translation_en_to_nl", tokenizer = tokenizer, model = model)
vec_Text <- c("This needs to be translated to Dutch", "This also needs to be translated to Dutch", "Just as this one has to")
translator(vec_Text)

[[1]]
[[1]]$translation_text
[1] "Dit moet vertaald worden naar het Nederlands"


[[2]]
[[2]]$translation_text
[1] "Dit moet ook vertaald worden naar het Nederlands"


[[3]]
[[3]]$translation_text
[1] "Net zoals deze moet"
```

With this approach, you do not need an app key and it runs locally on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach based on chatGPT which requires an API key :

```
library(chatgpt)
question <- "Can you translate the following sentence from English to Dutch : This also needs to be translated to Dutch"
Sys.setenv(OPENAI_API_KEY = "xxx")
chatgpt::reset_chat_session()
ask_chatgpt(question)

*** ChatGPT input:

Can you translate the following sentence from English to Dutch : This also needs to be translated to Dutch

[1] "Dit moet ook vertaald worden naar het Nederlands."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach with chatGPT with Azure of Microsoft :

```
library(reticulate)

conda_Env <- conda_list()

if(any(conda_Env[, 1] == "azureGPT") == FALSE)
{
  reticulate::conda_create(envname = "azureGPT", packages = c("openai"), python_version = "3.9.16")
}

reticulate::use_condaenv(condaenv = "azureGPT")
openai <- import(module = "openai")
openai$api_type <- "azure"
openai$api_base <- "https://yyy.openai.azure.com/"
openai$api_version <- "2023-07-01-preview"
openai$api_key <- "xxx"

messages <- list(list(role = 'system',
                      content = 'You will me to translate from english to dutch.'),
                 list(role = 'user',
                      content = 'Translate from english to dutch the following sentence : This needs to be translated to Dutch'))

model <- openai$ChatCompletion
response <- model$create(engine = "GPT35", 
                         messages = messages,
                         temperature = 0,
                         max_tokens = 350L,
                         top_p = 0.95,
                         frequency_penalty = 0,
                         presence_penalty = 0,
                         stop = NULL)

response$choices

{
  "index": 0,
  "finish_reason": "stop",
  "message": {
    "role": "assistant",
    "content": "Dit moet vertaald worden naar het Nederlands."
  },
  "content_filter_results": {
    "hate": {
      "filtered": false,
      "severity": "safe"
    },
    "self_harm": {
      "filtered": false,
      "severity": "safe"
    },
    "sexual": {
      "filtered": false,
      "severity": "safe"
    },
    "violence": {
      "filtered": false,
      "severity": "safe"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
library(stringr)
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
text_To_Translate <- "La tutela de Vieux-la-Romaine est une "
text_To_Translate <- str_replace_all(string = text_To_Translate, pattern = "[:space:]", replacement = "%20")
url <- paste0('https://translate.google.com/?hl=fr&sl=fr&tl=en&text=', text_To_Translate, '&op=translate')
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(10)
doc <- IEApp$document()
web_Obj <- doc$querySelector("#yDmH0d > c-wiz > div > div.ToWKne > c-wiz > div.OlSOob > c-wiz > div.ccvoYb > div.AxqVh > div.OPPzxe > c-wiz.sciAJc > div > div.usGWQd > div > div.lRu31 > span.HwtZe > span > span")
text <- web_Obj$outerHTML()
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(text, ">.*</span>"))
[1] ">The tutela of Vieux-la-Romaine is a</span>"
```

Comment: It fails for me on the web_Obj line with the following error: `Error in .COM(x, name, ...) : 
  Cannot locate 0 name(s) querySelector in COM object (status = -2147352570)`

Comment: I see that the problem is the same cookie request, but once you first click through cookies manually, it works on the next run. Not sure yet if the manual fix persists after a restart

Comment: On my end, I do not have a cookie request so it is hard to help you further. What you could do is to create a "web_Obj" to click on the Cookie button automatically with internet explorer. You have an example here of how you can click on a button with internet explorer from R : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041563/webscraping-in-r-https-webform/70323444#70323444

Comment: Thanks. Never used RDCOMClient for a browser before today (rvest or rselenium). Can this method be adapted for image translation by Google? How does one load a name space for doc or web_Obj?

Comment: (and by name space I was referring to the list of available methods)

Comment: It could be, but it depends on the website you would use to do an image translation. Which web site would you use to perform the image translation?

Comment: I was referring to image translation by Google, as in `https://translate.google.com/?hl=en&sl=en&tl=no&text=Try%20Norwegian&op=images`